# What is the difference between accepted and is_accepted?

Tags: support, discussion, api-v2, answers

I saw there are two fields in [answer type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer).

One is `accepted`, introduced in v2.2 and needs `private_info` access.
While another one is `is_accepted` without these limits.

Can somebody give an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the answer is the accepted answer, `is_accepted` is true and anyone can see it.

`accepted` is set to true only if the *currently authenticated* user is the one who has accepted the answer.

---

For instance, if I obtain an `access_token` with the `private_info` privilege and call:

```
/2.2/questions/30028657/answers?site=stackoverflow&key={YOUR APP KEY}&access_token={VALID TOKEN FOR THAT APP}&filter=!%294k-FmUi-xgG3sdSdPz*cQNNqR0A
```

I see:

```
"items":[
    {
        "owner":{
            "user_id":2435473,
            "display_name":"pankajparkar"
        },
        "accepted":false,
        "is_accepted":true,
        "score":2,
        "creation_date":1430738287,
        "answer_id":30028806,
        "question_id":30028657
    },
    {
        "owner":{
            "user_id":4494320,
            "display_name":"Mike"
        },
        "accepted":false,
        "is_accepted":false,
        "score":1,
        "creation_date":1430738255,
        "answer_id":30028794,
        "question_id":30028657
    },
    etc.
```

`accepted` is false, because I do not own that question.

On questions owned by the authenticated user, `accepted` == `is_accepted` for any answers to that question.

Note that you need to use a filter that returns `accepted`, as this is not present by default.

Comment: Thanks Adams. I met another problem while calling request. http://stackapps.com/questions/6306/can-not-request-info-after-oauth