# Can not request info after OAuth

Tags: support, api, authentication, oauth2

I am following The implicit OAuth 2.0 flow Guide:

My client ID is `4709` while key is `RoZwtHUrhMP088oVGCMlxA((`

I appended my URL as:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4709&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
```

and trying to oauth.

And I got this URL as returned:
`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=I*SJDoi6W(TUAz2BRCEzbw))&expires=86399`

I notice that `I*SJDoi6W(TUAz2BRCEzbw))` is the `access_token`.

When I try to call the request as [this answer of my question](https://stackapps.com/a/6300/33134) .

So I call

`http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30028657/answers?site=stackoverflow&key=RoZwtHUrhMP088oVGCMlxA((&access_token=I*SJDoi6W(TUAz2BRCEzbw))&filter=!%294k-FmUi-xgG3sdSdPz*cQNNqR0A`

Unfortunately, I got 403 Error:

> {"error_id":403,"error_message":"`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.","error_name":"access_denied"}

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second call must be `https:`.

You *actually* got an error like:

```
"error_id":406,
"error_message":"Access token sent over non-HTTPS request, it has been invalidated",
"error_name":"access_token_compromised"
```

On the first attempt.

Only subsequent attempts, with the same token, would yield the `'key' is not valid for passed 'access_token'` error.

When I call:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4709&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
```

And get:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=wdR8Lm7m4ibD48lfrCcFxQ))&expires=86399
```

and then call:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/30028657/answers?site=stackoverflow&key=RoZwtHUrhMP088oVGCMlxA((&access_token=wdR8Lm7m4ibD48lfrCcFxQ))&filter=!)4k-FmUi-xgG3sdSdPz*cQNNqR0A
```

It works for me.  (Before I invalidated the token, that is. ;) )

Comment: That's exactly!

Comment: So if I try second attempts, I will get a 403 error? How to avoid it cause I don't want to access a single access_token again for per request.

Comment: No, you'll only get the 403 *because* you got the previous 406 error.  Just keep everything on `https:` and you'll be okay.