# quota_remaining is decreasing much faster than expected

Tags: bug, rate-limit, quota

I registered an app and tried to make a couple of requests via Chrome (without actually creating any application yet). The thing that is really confusing is that with making a single request, `quota_remaining` decreased by a few thousand.

Details:

1. Registered app
2. Starting quota **10 000**
3. Sent request below (only once, via Chrome):
   `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=microservices&site=stackoverflow&filter=!*fZOXQJitmsheGqKd_WMzQ.84jVWfBO.1Sqt*&key=XXXXXX`
4. In response received `"quota_remaining":7524`, so it already decreased by 2.5k with single request
5. made request below (again only once, via chrome):
   `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=docker&site=stackoverflow&filter=!*fZOXQJitmsheGqKd_WMzQ.84jVWfBO.1Sqt*&key=XXXXXX`
6. In response received `"quota_remaining":7463`. It is obviously much better than 2.5k decrease, but still decrease by 100 on single request doesn't make any sense to me

I understand, from the documentation, that each single request should decrease quota by 1 only.

Does anyone know if it is expected behavior? And if it is, how to I avoid depleting quota that fast?

Comment: Works okay for me (using my own app key).  Are you behind a corporate/university/country firewall with a lot of other people?  Sure you don't have other SE apps running?

Comment: Thanks for checking this request, so it is not a filter issue. I don't have any other SE apps. Yes, I'm behind corporate firewall with about couple of thousands potentially sharing same IP (not sure about this part). Actually before registering an app, I tried this request once without auth, and then few minutes later when I tried similar request on different tag - it said either my quota got depleted or backoff flag and I need to wait ~16000 seconds till next request. After that I decided to try registered app so shared IP wouldn't matter.Do you think corporate network still have some effect

Comment: 16000 seconds; that's over 4 hours!  Your IP must've been seriously abusing the API.  Maybe the quota weirdness is a precursor to a permanent ban? ... Anyway, see [the Throttles page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle): Since you are not using an `access_token`, the 10K quota limit is shared by everything on your firewall's IP.

Comment: it may be explaining everything... I thought &key=XXXXX IS usage of access_token? at least I'm passing access_token as key parameter. I was looking for specific example on how to pass access_token but didn't find any. In app usage with keys/tokens documentation - in key section it says "Pass this as key when making requests against the Stack Exchange API to receive a higher request quota.". So I thought it is all I need. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No `key` and `access_token` are very different.  `key` identifies an app.  `access_token` identifies a logged-in *user* of that app.  See [here](http://stackapps.com/q/6306/7653) for a Q&D example of using an `access_token` (with the client-side OAuth flow enabled in the app's settings).