# BountyHunter - an app to track reputation of a group of people

Tags: app, placeholder, reputation

This is a demo app I am building to track the Stack Exchange reputations of people in our (company) group.

[Github repository](https://github.com/abhinaykumar/Bounty-Hunter)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am about to push some more code. Its for reputation on Stackoverflow.

Comment: should I be able to use it now @BrockAdams . I am continuously getting a "Maintenance on progress" message while trying to login through StackExchange OAuth.

Comment: Deleted my obsolete comments.  Anywho, it should still work.  I'll double check in a moment.  Is your error the same as [this report](http://stackapps.com/questions/6978/we-are-currently-offline-for-maintenance-message-when-authenticating-to-stacke)?

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I facing. @BrockAdams .

Comment: @BrockAdams I understand that has nothing to do with the api call, its just that login is the first thing user will do here and then rest of the things will happen. So, I just thought to bring it to your knowledge. btw thanks for quick response :)

Comment: Authorization still works for me, at least in the pre-logged-in, implicit case.  Try [the recipe in this answer and see if it works for you](http://stackapps.com/a/6308/7653). IMPORTANT:  Just paste those three URLS, sequentially, in your browser, but change the `access_token` part to what you get in the address bar after the first URL.

Comment: OK, If I am not wrong that's for client side authentication. I am doing server side, It says `application not configured for implicit grants`. @BrockAdams

Comment: That example is client side. The first question is does auth work for you at all?.  Try that recipe exactly as stated, changing nothing but the `access_token`.

Comment: Yeah those links worked for me but when i tried the same by changing `client_id`,i got "application not created", "access denied" @BrockAdams

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43284/discussion-between-brock-adams-and-abhinay).